# Log Axis Client Requests and Responses Using Spring bean

Tags: spring, soap, jax-ws, axis

I have an integration set up with spring using Apache Axis as a SOAP client.

I am able to set up the client-config.wsdd to configure a handler as a class that is outside of the spring context. What I would like to do is configure the handler so that it is within the spring context. Is this possbile?

Here is my current `client-config.wsdd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment name="defaultClientConfig"
            xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
            xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">

    <handler name="log" type="java:xxx.xxx.handler.SOAPLogHandler">
    </handler>

    <globalConfiguration>
        <parameter name="disablePrettyXML" value="false"/>
        <requestFlow>
            <handler type="log"/>
        </requestFlow>
        <responseFlow>
            <handler type="log"/>
        </responseFlow>
    </globalConfiguration>

    <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender"/>
</deployment>
```

I also have the service registered with spring:

```
<bean id="wsYPSoap" class="xxx.xxx.core.ws.WsYPSoapProxy">
    <constructor-arg value="${xxx.service.url}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to use Spring bean directly as a handler for Axis client and exactly for the purposes of logging request/response details.

It seems that currently there is no easy and straightforward way to do this.

There is, however, a way to do it by accessing a Spring bean from Axis handler via application root context. There are few issues here:

- Axis handlers are instantiated when they are needed as a simple classes (not beans)
- handler instances can't rely on existence of any servlet (or, i.e. Faces) context at the time their `invoke()` method is called

Because of this, you have to place your Spring bean in the root application context. Problem is that you can't access the application context in the usual way (i.e. via `ServletContext` of `FacesContext`). Workaround for this is to create your own `ApplicationContextAware` bean which will store the reference to root application context on app startup for you to use in Axis handler.

Minimal `ApplicationContextAware` bean implementation example:

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext rootAppContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        rootAppContext = ctx;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return rootAppContext;
    }
}
```

and in `application-context.xml` declare the bean:

```
<bean id="appContextProvider" lazy-init="false" class="package.where.the.class.is.ApplicationContextProvider" />
```

Notice the `lazy-init="false"` in declaration, **this is important**. Since this bean is not referenced (or auto-wired) anywhere, Spring will not create the instance of it ever, because Spring uses lazy strategy for bean creation. Setting `lazy-init` to false makes sure that the bean is created on app startup.

Provided that you have your DB logging bean (implemented by `DBLogBean` class) properly set up and loaded/created by Spring, you can access it in the Axis handler i.e. like this:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
if (ctx != null) {
    DBLogBean bean = (DBLogBean) ctx.getBean("yourDBLogBeanId");
    if( bean != null ) {
        bean.doLogOrSomething();
    }
}
```

Make sure you check if `ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()` returns `null` or not before fetching DB bean from context. Note now you also must check if `ctx.getBean()` returns `null` or not.

If this is not an option (i.e. for some reason you must have the DB bean whenever Axis handler is called), then you have to make sure Axis handler is only ever called *after* `ApplicationContextProvider` bean has been created. That topic, however, is out of scope here ;)

> NOTE: Creating beans by using `lazy-init="false"` is **not** a
>   preferred way of creating bean instances. Beans should be
>   auto-wired/referenced by other beans/code and left to Spring to manage
>   their life cycle. For example, one downside of forcing bean creation
>   on startup is you can't be sure at which point they have been created
>   and become available, unless you take extra steps to handle that (or
>   make sure they are referenced by other code but then, why use
>   `lazy-init="false"` in the first place?).